# Use tcolorboxes as nodes to create arrows with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tcolorbox

I'm trying to draw an arrow between 2 tcolorbox. But I don't know how to do it, because tikz requires "nodes"

If I have this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=0.8in,right=0.8in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{makecell, hhline}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}
\newcommand\whitecell[1]{\cellcolor{white}{#1}}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=4.5cm,
halign=center,valign=center,
square]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=4.5cm,
halign=center,valign=center,
square]
This is a \textbf{tcolorbox}.
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

How do you make an horizontal arrow in-between? 
Cheers

Comment: Even if the linked question is not about `tcolorbox`, the answer uses it in the solution. :) hope it helps

Comment: I'm having a look at it now, trying it on my code. I have never seen the 'remember as' command in a colourbox, so i'll let you know

Comment: yep it worked super fine, I am really happy :)

Comment: Glad it helped!